# Can I make a piece of text ignore formatting changes applied by its outer context?

Tags: fonts, text-decorations, emphasis

I have a command which formats a piece of text a certain way. Simple example:

```
\begincommand{\myformat}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

I want to be able to place this command inside other text formatting commmands and have those "outer" commands have no effect on the text enclosed in my command.

If I write

```
\textbf{Some \myformat{example} text.}
\emph{Some \myformat{example} text.}
```

I want this to be displayed the same as if I had written

```
\textbf{Some }\myformat{example}\textbf{ text.}
\emph{Some }\myformat{example}\emph{ text.}
```

Is it possible to "protect" the formatting on a piece of text in situations like this? So that all text formatting applied *within* `\myformat` is applied, but all further formatting is ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\myformat` to change the font used to `\normalfont` before setting new styles/shapes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\myformat}{\normalfont\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Some \texttt{example} text.}
\emph{Some \texttt{example} text.}

\textbf{Some \myformat{example} text.}
\emph{Some \myformat{example} text.}

\end{document}
```

Using `\DeclareTextFontCommand` as opposed to merely

```
\newcommand{\myformat}[1]{{\normalfont\ttfamily #1}}
```

makes the command

- [robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764),
- work in math mode (since the text is placed in a box), and
- inserts the appropriate italic correction (if needed).

Comment: Or, `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\myformat}{\normalfont\ttfamily}` (this is actually better, since it handles automatic insertion of the italic correction).

Comment: … and defines a robust command, too!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: That's neat. I'll add it.

Comment: Yes, it is superior under all respects, I think.  Drawback: `can be used only in preamble`.

Comment: OK, after the edit I have no longer withheld my upvote ;-)  But there’s one more Good Thing about `\DeclareTextFontCommand` I’d mention: if the `amsmath` package is loaded, the `\myformat` command will automagically switch to the correct size when used, for example, in a susbcript (inside math).  In other words, in that case the argument is wrapped in a `\hbox` that, in turn, is wrapped in a `\mathchoice`.