# How can I hyphenate before capital letters in \ttfamily?

Tags: hyphenation

A while ago I asked [How can I allow line-breaks before a double-colon (::) in \texttt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358925/how-can-i-allow-line-breaks-before-a-double-colon-in-texttt) This question is about extending the line-breaking behaviour to include hypenation.

The given solution solves the problem as it was originally asked:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cppstring}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_spraff_cppstring_tl { #1 }
  % change _ to a printable underscore
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \cO\_ } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % change :: to \linebreak[0]::
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { :: } { \c{linebreak}[0]:: } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % print the result
  {\normalfont\ttfamily \tl_use:N \l_spraff_cppstring_tl }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(I have tweaked this slightly from the given solution, I use `\normalfont\ttfamily` instead of `\texttt` because of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354092/can-i-make-a-piece-of-text-ignore-formatting-changes-applied-by-its-outer-contex).)

This solution doesn't always work for my document:

[image]

I think it would be an improvement to allow hyphenation in some cases. Specifically, before a capital letter in CamelCase names. I would like to allow hyphenation such as this:

```
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum MyNamespaceName::SomeType::Nested-
Type::member_function
```

I want to retain the line-break-before-double-colon behaviour that I already have. **How can I extend this `\cppstring` command to hyphenate before capital letters?**

I don't know what the hyphenation rules are in detail, but this will ideally happen as little as possible -- i.e. only when an overfull hbox would otherwise be drawn. *Minimising the hyphenation is desirable, preventing the overfull hboxes is critical.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the replacement that a capital letter `<capital letter>` which is not preceded by a word boundary is changed into `\-<capital letter>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cppstring}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_spraff_cppstring_tl { #1 }
  % change _ to a printable underscore
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \cO\_ } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % change :: to \linebreak[0]::
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { :: } { \c{linebreak}[0]:: } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % change capital letter X to \-X
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\B[A-Z]) } { \c{-}\1 } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % print the result
  {\normalfont\ttfamily \tl_use:N \l_spraff_cppstring_tl }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\cppstring{MyNamespaceName::SomeType::NestedType::member_function}

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\cppstring{MyNamespaceName::SomeType::NestedType::member_function}
}

\end{document}
```

The second example shows all added hyphenation points, in order to see you don't get them between `::` and a capital letter.

[image]